# Do illusion spells work on dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As I said, will stuff like Pacify/Harmony work on Dragons? If not, does it require any perks to do so?

Comment: Perhaps ask your second point as a new question to get better responses

Comment: Yes, one post, one question 'round here. :) I've edited out the extra question, but do feel free to post it on its own. (You can look at the edit history by clinking the timestamp above the "edited by" icon if you want to copy-paste the old text.)

Answer (score 3):

No.

> Dragons are completely immune to Illusion spells of any kind, regardless of skill level or perks.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion)

Comment: Does this mean they can see through invisibility or hear you when you have the muffle spell active?

Comment: @Jtenorj3 no, but you can't affect them with any illusion spells like frenzy, calm, etc